# Why must a powerlet or a CO2 charger and other gas containers be cylindrical in shape?

Tags: pressure

So I'm a student working on some design ideas involving gas canisters for flotation devices, and I was wondering why all the gas canisters/cartridges I've seen so far are all cylindrical. Is it just a norm, or is there an actual reason for it? Would a flat, rectangular metal gas container work as well?

Answer (score 0):

The ideal shape would be a sphere.  The reason for the cylinder is that it contains the largest volume for the amount of material (after a sphere) - try working out how much area is enclosed by a circle and a corresponding square with the same perimeter.

Another reason is that there are no corners which could lead to stress concentrations which would allow cracks to start - the same reason for round windows in ship's hulls and aircraft bodies

Comment: I'm quite certain the stress on the corners is far more important than the volume.

Comment: @CortAmmon but is a very short scale phenomena, rounding the corners even 1mm would reduce the stress concentration enormously